# Merging Audio Streams in realtime using Wowza Media Server

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-streaming, wowza

My company is implementing an audio chat server using Wowza Media Server, but we need some guidance to help us solve the following bandwidth problem:

**SITUATION:**

We have an audio chat system, whereby users can collaborate with others. N users publish to their own audio channel, while subscribing to N-1 audio channels (the other users minus their own).

**PROBLEM:**

Bandwidth gets large rather quickly when you start to add more users. For example, say 4 users are online --   User A, User B, User C, & User D. If each user is publishing an 8kbps audio channel, to which all other user's are subscribing, then the total bandwidth utilized will be a hefty 96kbps:

> User A = 24kbps (from 3 streams: 8kbps from subscribing to user B, 8kbps from subscribing to user C, & 8kbps from subscribing to user D) +
>
> User B = 24kbps (from 3 streams: 8kbps from subscribing to user A, user C, & user D) +
>
> User C = 24kbps (from 3 streams: 8kbps from subscribing to user A, user B, & user D) +
>
> User D = 24kbps (from 3 streams: 8kbps from subscribing to user A, user B, & user C) = 96kbps total

**WHAT I THINK WE NEED TO DO:**

Merge the audio channels (in realtime) of all user channels online (except one's own), and have each user subscribe to that unique, newly merged channel, like so:

> User A = 8kbps (from 1 merged stream of users B, C, & D) +
>
> User B = 8kbps (from 1 merged stream of users A, C, & D) +
>
> User C = 8kbps (from 1 merged stream of users A, B, & D) +
>
> User D = 8kbps (from 1 merged stream of users A, B, & C) = 32kbps total

You can see where this problem can get out of control quickly, as this example is with only 4 people online at a time. Say you add one more for a total of 5, then under our current setup, bandwidth would be using 20 distinct subscription streams for a total of 160kbps. Whereas, the optimal merged solution would only add an additional 8kbps per additional user, so a total of 40kbps for 5 users, 48kbps for 6 users, etc.

**SO,** does anyone have any suggestions as to how I should go about making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You might be over-analysing it. Only one user is likely to be talking at any point in time (you could assume some overlap, as in normal conversation). If you have voice activity detection (simple thresholding might work) then you don't have to send data on a user's stream if they're not talking. This should mean your overall bandwidth would be, say, 110% of a single user's.